# Firebase got crashed when binding isolate process

Tags: android, firebase

I have initialized Firebase on Application onCreate() :

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

then try to binding isolate process on Activity

```
bindService(intent, mIsolatedServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Firebase has crashed with below exception, Could someone help me to fix this bug?

```
2020-05-25 11:47:13.700 27703-27703/com.test.process_v:tmp:com.test.process.IsolatedService W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /data/user/0/com.test.process_v/shared_prefs: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2020-05-25 11:47:13.700 27703-27703/com.test.process_v:tmp:com.test.process.IsolatedService W/SystemServiceRegistry: No service published for: user
2020-05-25 11:47:13.701 27703-27703/com.test.process_v:tmp:com.test.process.IsolatedService D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2020-05-25 11:47:13.702 27703-27703/com.test.process_v:tmp:com.test.process.IsolatedService E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.darvin.security_v:tmp:com.test.process.IsolatedService, PID: 27703
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.test.process.App: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.UserManager.isUserUnlockingOrUnlocked(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6465)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.swift.sandhook.SandHook.callOriginMethod(SandHook.java:185)
        at com.swift.sandhook.xposedcompat.hookstub.HookStubManager.hookBridge(HookStubManager.java:375)
        at SandHookerNew_5sm3dthec8858ee0to4kj3c1ge.hook(Unknown Source:51)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.UserManager.isUserUnlockingOrUnlocked(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:457)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:443)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:178)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:528)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:355)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310)
        at com.test.process.App.onCreate(App.java:32)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.swift.sandhook.SandHook.callOriginMethod(SandHook.java:185) 
        at com.swift.sandhook.xposedcompat.hookstub.HookStubManager.hookBridge(HookStubManager.java:375) 
        at SandHookerNew_5sm3dthec8858ee0to4kj3c1ge.hook(Unknown Source:51) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

If Firebase has initialized on Activity then no crashed happen.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: app crashed after this code "bindService(intent, mIsolatedServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);"

Comment: Please share the code where you are calling `isUserUnlockingOrUnlocked()`.

Comment: @AlexMamo Firebase has called it, You can check at line 301 of FirebaseApp.class

Comment: I was hit by the same exact issue. My solution is similar to yours where the initiation of the firebase moved to the activity instead, other than that, I tried to initiate the isolate before the firebaseApp. But if you find a better answer it would be great to

Answer (score 1):

Check in your application onCreate() if process that runs it is isolated. If not - run initialization of Firebase.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    if (!android.os.Process.isIsolated()) {
       //init firebase
    }
}
```

Comment: If the application does run in isolation, will it work just fine?